# Compare records of two flat files and write the un-matching record of FILE-1 to Output

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I have 2 files File-1 and File-2. The records in both files are in descending order.  File-1 may have some extra record at the top. I want to write all the records in File-1 that are not present in File-2.

```
File-1:- Sample
2019-08-06 XXXX
2019-08-06 XYXX
2019-08-06 XXYX
2019-08-05 XXYX
2019-08-05 XXYY
2019-08-04 XXYX
2019-08-03 XXYX
2019-08-03 XZYX

File-2:- Sample
2019-08-05 XXYX
2019-08-05 XXYY
2019-08-04 XXYX
2019-08-03 XXXX
2019-08-03 XZYX


Output:-
2019-08-06 XXXX
2019-08-06 XYXX
2019-08-06 XXYX
2019-08-03 XXYX
```

Please let me know the pseudo code.

Comment: Date + X*** is one record in the file. But it came out a single record.

Comment: A google of "two file match psudo code + cobol" returned "about 562,000" hits. And whilst we are at it, because you are on a mainframe they are not files but datasets. Files have a different connotation under zOS more equivalent to a stream in C etc.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?  Also, it's unclear to me what "File-1 may have some extra record at the top" means.  Is it a header record, is it optional, is there more than one?

Comment: Read File-1, take the date field to WS. Then read File-2 until eof. 
IF date in File-1 is Greater than or Equal to date in File-2, then process the record otherwise continue with the read of File-2. 
In Process para, if dates are equal close the File-2 and Open again. So that we can read the records from top. 
If the date in File-1 is greater, then write the record to output file and close and open the File-2.
The frequent CLOSE & OPEN takes much of the CPU. Plz suggest some alternatives. The record r in descending order of date. So File-1 may have xtra records with current date.

Comment: I would suggest that none of those 562000 hits would advocate what you are thinking. Why read to the end? Read until the dat changes. Then get next date. If dates in dataset1 have no records on dataset2 write them out - if you need to. If records on dataset2 have no matching date record on dataset1 then write them out if required to do so. If dates match then process records on dataset2 until the dates no longer match.

Comment: Consider how you would do this if you had two stacks of physical cards.  The equivalent of picking up cards is to `READ` them.  The equivalent of comparing the two cards is to use the `IF` statement.  The equivalent of putting the cards into a new pile is the `WRITE` statement.  Repeating the above steps until you have finished all of the cards is a `PERFORM` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Open both input files for reading
Open output file for writing
while not eof file2
read file2
    while file1 > file2 and not eof file1
        read file1
        write file1 to output
    end while  
end while
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PERFORM 000-OPEN.
PERFORM 100-PROCESS THRU 100-PROCESS-EXIT
UNTILL END-File-1 AND END-File-2. (Where END-File will be declare as PIC X(2) VALUE '10')
PERFORM 200-CLOSE-FILE THRU 200-CLOSE-FILE-EXIT.
*************************************************************
000-OPEN.
will perform opening the 2 files in INPUT mode and 3 output file in OUTPUT 
mode.
000-OPEN-EXIT.
**
100-PROCESS.
**
will perform READ operation for 2 input files, then will compare first 
record from both files.

IF File-1(REC-1) NOT= File-2(REC-1)
WRITE File-3 (For unmatched Records)
READ File-1 AND File-2.
END-IF.
```